# How to fix overlapping of previous fragment's collapsing toolbar and current fragment's content?

Tags: android, xml

I'm new to android, and want to find solution for the following situation:
  I have implemented fragment called profile, In which I have collapsing toolbar and TabLayout. Whenever I clicked on any of the button of current fragment, It will display next page as a new fragment accordingly.Next fragment have it's own toolbar.

> Problem: Whenever I scroll the content, previous fragment Collapsing Toolbar appears on top. It overlaps the current fragment.

I have tried the solution using Framelayout and "fitSystemWindows = true".Another solution I have tried is giving "clickable=true" to next fragment. None of them helped me. Where I made a mistake?

Here's the overview of my code:

ProfileFragment is loaded from MainActivity which has bottom navigation view.

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.navigation_profile:
                    ProfileFragment f5=new ProfileFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction ft5= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft5.replace(R.id.fragment_container,f5,"");
                    ft5.commit();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    tools:context="com.work.workapp.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container">
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView/>

</LinearLayout>
```

profile_fragment.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/profile_main">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <LinearLayout
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <ImageView/>
                <TextView/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

                <RelativeLayout>
                    <!-- Settings Button -->
                    <!-- Edit Button -->
                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_profile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[profile-toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cdqzn.jpg)
[collapse toolbar - Tab post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgRHc.jpg)

tab_post and tab_work Adapter files:

```
/* Button click event from post Tab of tablayout*/
myViewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            RequestsFragment req_list = new RequestsFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = ((FragmentActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.container_profile, req_list, "");
            ft.addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    });
```

When Click on "5" - button on Post tab, following fragment displayed:
[Button click on Post tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gqKs.jpg)

When scroll on above fragment, previous fragment's collapsed toolbar appears on new fragment:
[content and toolbar overlaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBhoS.jpg)

No error message appears. App is successfully running. I want to remove this Overlapping.

Comment: I'm really not following your description of the behavior, but I will point out that transacting a `Fragment` into `container_profile` does not remove or replace any other `View`s in that layout that don't belong to `Fragment`s. That new `Fragment` in the `FrameLayout` is just stacked on top of the `AppBarLayout` and `ViewPager` that are already there. If you're trying to replace the whole profile `Fragment`, you need to pass the `R.id` for the `ViewGroup` that it is in, not the `container_profile` that is inside of it.

Comment: I replaced new fragment with id of coordinatorlayout, but same thing happen.

Comment: If you mean `R.id.profile_main`, that is not the `ViewGroup` that the profile `Fragment` is in. That `<CoordinatorLayout>` is in its own layout.

Comment: Can you please give me solution by writing  code? I don’t get your point.

Comment: How exactly did you load the profile `Fragment`?

Comment: Question updated.Please refer code for ProfileFragment.

Comment: No, not its `onCreateView()`. How are loading `ProfileFragment`? Do you have a `<fragment>` element in your `Activity`'s layout for it? Or are you doing a dynamic transaction; e.g., `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(...)`?

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: `replace(R.id.fragment_container, ...)` – That's the `ViewGroup` that `ProfileFragment` is in. If you want to completely replace `ProfileFragment`, that's the `R.id` that you would need to pass in your other `FragmentTransaction`s.